# Space characters in text strings PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to output different variations of text but it does not seem to be working. I have tried the examples on the web but with no luck.

For example, If i do the following command:

```
<?php echo “Test”; ?>
```

The output on my webpage is "Test" with quotes rather than Test without quotes?
Shouldn't it output without the quotes?

If i put any spaces in my string, the page doesn't even load. For example:

```
<?php echo “Test Test”; ?>
```

Comment: Wrong quotes. Stop using MS Word as an IDE.

Comment: Sidenote: You do realize that those curly quotes `“ ”` will crash your code. Edit: This shouldn't be a "sidenote" but a: "Use regular quotes `"` ".

Comment: ohhhhh far out.. no wonder. I've wasted hours on this... boo

Answer (score 1):

You need other quotes:

```
<?php echo "Test Test"; ?>
```

The ones you were using come from `MS Word` and the blank page you're seeing is most likely due to an error being suppressed.